# Identity roles in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-identity

I have the application which has authentication and authorization with `JWT` token. I am using `ASP.NET Core Identity` for registering users. So my goal is to have two roles: manager and user. I have created `"RoleController"` that has `CRUD` operations and I successfully added these roles but next step is to attach these roles to users and my question starts from here...

What is the best practice to achieve this? I mean should I send `"Role"` field value when I register a new user? But in case like this, anyone can register as an manager. I thought to create different registration endpoints for Managers and Users but I don't know if it is best practice or not. So what can I do, how can I manage this role-based authentication and how can I register user with defined roles?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Identity UserManager to assign roles/custom roles for Users.
For example: `await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(poweruser, "Admin");`

Following this, you can also assign roles to users during SignUp/Registration so that after account creation, the person will have those roles. You can also create custom roles and save those in DB and map those while user registration.

For conjugated role/permission you can try Identity Policies too.

Comment: i know all that but my main problem is the following: should i manually type code for roles? i mean lets say user is filling registration form and i get this form in the back after submitting this data, how would i know which role should i attach to it? should i have also field for role in the form? how to separate manager and user registration from each other

Comment: You can create one superadmin/administrator user which can be created from code/query manually, then use that user to create dynamic roles and assign. And for manager/user registration separation, you can expose general registration for all users and separate registration for manager user. Also it can be achieved by one form if you put a toggle/dropdown there to select which user roles he wants to get registered.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very good question. In Generally, high-privileged accounts are provided by companies or organizations rather than registered by themselves. In my opinion, a simple way to achieve this is that when the user is successfully registered, you can provide an email address for users who want to be Managers to send applications, Then you can determine whether this user can become a Managers by this application. If you think this user can become Manager, You can add role by yourself, If not, Just do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I decide to achieve this goal in this way:

Simply, I created "**RoleController**" as you can see below:

```
using AutoMapper;
using Contracts.ViewModels;
using Domain.Entities;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace WOB.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin, Manager")]
    public class RoleController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole>? _roleManager;
        private readonly UserManager<User>? _userManager;
        private readonly IConfiguration? Configuration;
        private readonly IMapper? _mapper;

        public RoleController(
            RoleManager<IdentityRole>? roleManager, 
            UserManager<User> userManager,
            IMapper mapper,
            IConfiguration? configuration)
        {
            _roleManager = roleManager;
            _userManager = userManager;
            _mapper = mapper;
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllRoles(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            var roles = await _roleManager.Roles.ToListAsync(cancellationToken);

            if(roles == null)
            {
                return BadRequest("Unable to get roles.");
            }

            return Ok(roles);
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpGet("{roleId}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetRoleById(string? roleId)
        {
            var role = await _roleManager.FindByIdAsync(roleId);

            if(role == null)
            {
                return BadRequest("Unable to get the role.");
            }

            return Ok(role);
        }

        [HttpPost("[action]")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateCustomRole([FromBody] RoleModel? roleModel)
        {
            if(roleModel == null)
            {
                return BadRequest($"{nameof(roleModel)} cannot be null.");
            }

            var role = _mapper.Map<IdentityRole>(roleModel);

            IdentityResult result = await _roleManager.CreateAsync(role);

            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                return BadRequest("Unable to create a role.");
            }

            return Ok();
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        // These controller create roles and them users in advance
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateRolesAndUsers()
        {
            // Checking if admin role already exists
            bool exists = await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync("Admin");

            if (!exists)
            {
                // First we are creating Admin role
                var role = new IdentityRole();
                role.Name = "Admin";

                await _roleManager.CreateAsync(role);

                // Then we are creating User that will have a Admin role
                var user = new User();
                string email = Configuration["AdminSettings:Email"];
                string password = Configuration["AdminSettings:Password"];

                user.UserName = user.Email = email;
                user.PasswordHash = _userManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(user, password);

                IdentityResult result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, password);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, role.Name);
                }else
                {
                    return BadRequest("Unable to create a Admin role.");
                }
            }

            // Checking if Manager role already exists
            exists = await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync("Manager");

            if (!exists)
            {
                // First we are creating Manager role
                var role = new IdentityRole();
                role.Name = "Manager";

                await _roleManager.CreateAsync(role);

                // Then we are creating User that will have a Manager role
                var user = new User();
                string email = Configuration["ManagerSettings:Email"];
                string password = Configuration["ManagerSettings:Password"];

                user.UserName = user.Email = email;
                user.PasswordHash = _userManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(user, password);

                IdentityResult result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, password);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, role.Name);
                }else
                {
                    return BadRequest("Unable to create a Manager role.");
                }

            }


            // Checking if Manager role already exists
            exists = await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync("User");

            if (!exists)
            {
                // First we are creating Manager role
                var role = new IdentityRole();
                role.Name = "User";

                IdentityResult result = await _roleManager.CreateAsync(role);

                if (!result.Succeeded)
                {
                    return BadRequest("Unable to create a User role.");
                }

            }

            return Ok();
        }

        [HttpDelete("{roleId}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteRole(string? roleId)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(roleId))
            {
                return BadRequest($"{nameof(roleId)} cannot be null or empty.");
            }

            var role = await _roleManager.FindByIdAsync(roleId);

            IdentityResult result = await _roleManager.DeleteAsync(role);

            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                return BadRequest("Unable to delete the role.");
            }

            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have created method "**CreateRolesAndUsers**" in which I have pre-defined: **Admin**, **Manager** and **User** roles creation. **There is one problem about it and i will talk about it later.**

Main logic of this method is to check if particular roles already exist, if not then create them and also create users that are relevant to them. **Emails** and **Passwords** for Admin and Manager roles are pre-defined in **appsettings.json** and without problem i am creating roles and their users.

Also i have created another method to create a custom roles.

One problem about this solution is next:
When the application runs, you have to manually call this endpoint to add these roles into database. I don't know if it is possible to automatically call this method when an app builds and add these roles instantly in the database without manually calling it.

It could be the worst solution but at this time, it was the idea that i could thought of and most importantly, it does its job

Comment: You could create another thread before running app.Run() in program.cs

and have it check keep checking your health endpoint, and then when it does use your RoleService.EnsureRolesCreated(); 

then when it's done the thread / task will die :)

also found this for using services before app is running

await using var scope = app.Services.CreateAsyncScope();
using var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<DataContext>();
await db.Database.MigrateAsync(); 

credit to ˈvɔlə

Comment: I haven't tried it yet but it seems more efficient and understandable, than my current solution. That is really helpful thanks :)